# How to construct and conditionally assign to a new vector based on another bool vector in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to construct a new vector (of `float64`) filled with `NaN` with length `N`, and then assign part of it with another vector (of `float64`) based on yet another `boolean` vector.

This could be easily done in python (numpy), for example,

```
import numpy as np

N = 5

a = np.empty(N, dtype=float)
a.fill(np.nan)

b = [True, False, True, False, False]
c = [1.1, 5.3]

a[b] = c
# a = [1.1, nan, 5.3, nan, nan]
```

What should be the idiomatic and efficient way to achieve this in Rust?

Comment: I don't see what is the difficulty to code it yourself, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e5048369027ecad3d51e77cf68ee4fca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really the **one** idiomatic way in Rust. There's many possible ways. But there are in fact a couple of best practices. The most important one is:

- Use iterators (`.iter()`) instead of index operators (`[..]`). Index operators perform out-of-bounds checks (because Rust is free of undefined behaviour, and out-of-bounds access would be undefined behaviour) and are therefore slow(-ish).

Let me show you two possible ways of achieving that.

If you create a `NaN` array and then assing the values, it would be much more efficient to do both at the same time. Like this: (thanks @Stargateur)

```rust
fn main() {
    let b = vec![true, false, true, false, false];
    let c = vec![1.1, 5.3];

    let mut i = c.into_iter();
    let d: Vec<_> = b
        .into_iter()
        .map(|cond| {
            cond.then_some(())
                .and_then(|_| i.next())
                .unwrap_or(f64::NAN)
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{d:?}");
}
```

```
[1.1, NaN, 5.3, NaN, NaN]
```

Explanation:

- `let mut i = c.into_iter()` creates the iterator `i` that will yield all elements of `c`.
- `b.into_iter()` creates an iterator that will yield all values of `b`.
- the `.map()` operation maps the boolean values to either `i.next()` or `f64::NAN`, depending on their value. `i.next()` inserts the next value of `c` whenever it is chosen.
- note the `i.next()` is part of a **closure**, meaning it only gets evaluated when it is actually required.
- `.collect()` takes all of the values and collects them into a vector (in this case).

Here's another example, for the scenario when we already have a vector and want to insert elements at specific places:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut data = [f64::NAN; 5];
    println!("{data:?}");

    let b = vec![true, false, true, false, false];
    let c = vec![1.1, 5.3];

    let mut c_values = c.into_iter();
    for (data_entry, b_value) in data.iter_mut().zip(b) {
        if b_value {
            if let Some(c_value) = c_values.next() {
                *data_entry = c_value;
            }
        }
    }

    println!("{data:?}");
}
```

```
[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[1.1, NaN, 5.3, NaN, NaN]
```

The principle is similar, but instead of `.collect()`ing, we iterate over it via `.iter_mut()`, so we can modify the existing data.